# FetchXml System.OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, fetchxml

As I've learnt from my google searches, MSCRM 2011 retrieves maximum 5000 entities but I want all my entities from a marketing list. As written on the web creating  "TurnOffFetchThrottling" field on HKLM\Software\Microsoft\MSCRM and set a value as 1 can solve this 5000 limit problem (In addition that I added MaxRowsPerPage field in the registry and set its values as more than 5000, but it also doesnt work). I tried it and I got System.OutOfMemory Exception error. By the way, when I delete "" and just get id attribute code works perfectly, but I need all attributes.  Here my fetchxml code:

```
enter code here
string fetchXml = "<fetch mapping='logical' >"
                  + "<entity name='" + entityType.LogicalName + "'>"
                    + "<all-attributes />"
                    + "<link-entity name='listmember' to='" + entityType.LogicalName + "id" + "' from='entityid'>"
                        + "<filter>"
                          + "<condition attribute='listid' operator='eq' value='" + chosenMarketingListGuid + "'/>"
                        + "</filter>"
                    + "</link-entity>"
                  + "</entity>"
                + "</fetch>";
```

I tried one more thing, I changed the fetchxml as:

```
enter code here
string fetchXml = "<fetch mapping='logical' >"
                  + "<entity name='listmember'>"
                    + "<all-attributes />"
                        + "<filter>"
                          + "<condition attribute='listid' operator='eq' value='" + chosenMarketingListGuid + "'/>"
                        + "</filter>"
                  + "</entity>"
                + "</fetch>";
```

As it is seen, I tried to retrieve just memberlists instead of contact/lead/account enttiy types, and it works! Howver I need contact/lead/account entity types not memberlist.
I'll be very grateful, if anyone helps me get out of this dark MSCRM tunnel!

here, full stack trace:

> [OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.]
>      System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityUtils.ReadContentAsBase64(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Int64 maxBufferSize) +197
>      System.ServiceModel.Security.EncryptedData.ReadCipherData(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Int64 maxBufferSize) +17
>      System.ServiceModel.Security.EncryptedType.ReadFrom(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Int64 maxBufferSize) +858
>      System.ServiceModel.Security.WSSecurityOneDotZeroReceiveSecurityHeader.DecryptBody(XmlDictionaryReader bodyContentReader, SecurityToken token) +80
>      System.ServiceModel.Security.WSSecurityOneDotZeroReceiveSecurityHeader.ExecuteMessageProtectionPass(Boolean hasAtLeastOneSupportingTokenExpectedToBeSigned) +1611
>      System.ServiceModel.Security.ReceiveSecurityHeader.Process(TimeSpan timeout, ChannelBinding channelBinding, ExtendedProtectionPolicy extendedProtectionPolicy) +1576
>      System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityProtocol.ProcessSecurityHeader(ReceiveSecurityHeader securityHeader, Message& message, SecurityToken requiredSigningToken, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState[] correlationStates) +205
>      System.ServiceModel.Security.SymmetricSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessageCore(Message& message, String actor, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState[] correlationStates) +637
>      System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessage(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState[] correlationStates) +371
>      System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityRequestChannel.ProcessReply(Message reply, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState correlationState, TimeSpan timeout) +471
>      System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout) +175
>      System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout) +22
>      System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout) +517
>      System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation) +88
>      System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message) +453
>      System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +237
>      Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IOrganizationService.RetrieveMultiple(QueryBase query) +0
>      Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy.RetrieveMultipleCore(QueryBase query) +626
>      Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy.RetrieveMultiple(QueryBase query) +39
>      IMPlugin.MarketingListHelper.getMembersAndCountOfChosenMarketingList(OrganizationServiceProxy service, Guid chosenMarketingListGuid, Entity entityType) in C:\Users\Zafer\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\IMPlugin\MarketingListHelper.cs:130
>      IMPlugin.IM_SMS.fillMainPanel(Double mainPanelHeight) in C:\Users\Zafer\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\IMPlugin\IM_SMS.aspx.cs:96
>      IMPlugin.IM_SMS.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Zafer\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\IMPlugin\IM_SMS.aspx.cs:42
>      System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
>      System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
>      System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason the 5000 limit exists is as a crude barrier to prevent exactly the issue you are encountering. You've by-passed the software limitation, you now need to overcome the hardware limitation (out of memory)...

You don't state how you are writing your code or what you are using your results for but I presume that there is additional processing that will following execution of your query. On this basis, my recommendation is that you introduce paging into your query expression and process records in batches of 5000.

A crude example:

```cs
// get records to process
string pagingCookie = null;
bool moreRecords = false;
int pageNum = 1;
DataCollection<Entity> myBatchOfRecords;    

bool continueProcessing = true;
while (continueProcessing)
{
    myBatchOfRecords = GetRecords(pageNum, ref pagingCookie, ref moreRecords);

    // process those records
    ProcessRecords(myBatchOfRecords);
    pageNum++;    
    continueProcessing = moreRecords;
}

function DataCollection<Entity> GetRecordsList(int pageNumber, ref string pagingCookie, ref bool moreRecords){
    var query = new QueryExpression(blahblahblah...);
    query.PageInfo = new PagingInfo { 
        Count = 5000, 
        PageNumber = pageNumber, 
        PagingCookie = pagingCookie };
    var results =  myOrgService.RetrieveMultiple(query);
    pagingCookie = matchedContacts.PagingCookie;
    moreRecords = matchedContacts.MoreRecords;
    return results;
}
```